# RegEx (replaceMatchesInString) does not work

Tags: objective-c, regex

Why does this RegEx with replaceMatchesInString return only "+" instead of "+123"?

```
NString *phoneNumberCleaned = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"++00123"];

NSString *strRegExPhoneNumberPrefixWrong = @"^([+0]*)\\d*$";

NSRegularExpression *regEx = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:strRegEx options:0 error:nil];

[regEx replaceMatchesInString:phoneNumberCleaned options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumberCleaned length]) withTemplate:@"+"];

return phoneNumberCleaned;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"++00123";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression 
   regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[+0]+(?=\\d*)" 
                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                           error:&error];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex 
           stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string 
                                    options:0 
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) 
                               withTemplate:@"+"];
return modifiedString;
```

The problem with your Regex was that `^([+0]*)\\d*$` is also matching the `\d*` which means, that it also gets replaced (you'd think that it would only replace your capture group, but evidently that isn't so). So you were essentialy replacing any string that matches the above pattern (which was including any trailing numbers), which in your case was the entire number.

What I used in my answer is called a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^[+0]+(?=\\d*)$
```

The lookahead basically means that you're looking for zero or more `+` or `0` that are followed by zero or more digits EXCLUDING the digits from the match. So you only replace the zeroes and pluses, not the digits following them.