# How to remove a substring using regular expression in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I have the following strings:

- mary poppins 50th anniversary edition
- the blues brothers 25th anniversary edition

How can I find "[one or two digits]th anniversary edition" substring and remove it to eventually end with:

- mary poppins
- the blues brothers

Please note that 50th and 25th are just examples, and in reality it could be any number from 1 to 99.

I guess it involves NSRegularExpression, but I'm not skilled with regular expression syntax...

Comment: "it could be any number from 1 to 99.": you can add a third digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You match a digit with `[0-9]`.
- If you want something to be matched 0 or 1 time, use a `?` after it
- You match anything (a single character) with `.`

So, you could use `" [0-9][0-9]?.. anniversary edition"` (because there's "th", "nd", and "st" to worry about).

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017608/3937 has some code for replacing regexes in strings

Comment: Thanks, looks great.

Comment: BTW, can I make the 'edition' optional using regex?

Comment: `( edition)?` should work.  Parens group things for using `?` or other operators.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `\d{1,2}.*$` and replace with `empty` string.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI5oS4/1)