# How can i trim spaces from between of a NSString while displaying in UI Label

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

I am getting the string value from web service.I need to remove spaces from between of a string. How can I do that?
Example:if string is `"A  ALL YEAR"` it must become `"A ALL YEAR"` while displaying the value in UILabel text.

I have attached the below image for clarification.

[image]

Comment: @vishnuvarthan I t is not a duplicate of what you are referring. Since it that they are trimming Leading & Trailing white spaces. Whereas i want to trim between spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *yourString = @"A  ALL YEAR";
NSCharacterSet *whitespaces = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSPredicate *noEmptyStrings = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];

NSArray *parts = [yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:whitespaces];
NSArray *filteredArray = [parts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:noEmptyStrings];
yourString = [filteredArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Output:- A ALL YEAR

Hope you need this. If this doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: @BrijeshSingh Great. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = "A All Time".components(separatedBy: " ")

let newString = str[0] + " " + str[1] + " " + str[3]
```

You can also use a for loop.

Comment: hardcoding? horrible solution

Comment: Value will not remain constant.The text & size can vary. since i have mention that i am getting the value from web service.

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSRegularExpression` class with this regex pattern:

```
\s{2,}
```

and replace is with `space`.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW5kW0/1)

Example of [NSRegualrExpression for string replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001530/regex-replacematchesinstring-does-not-work).